# searching for mutliple unique IDs using .where in cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to search through a collection in 1 attempt and pull out files with the ids: 420, 430, and 440.
looking at the documentation I see that I can write a function like .where("queueID", "==", 440)
how can I extend this to look for the other IDs at the same time? can I tack on more .where's?

Comment: I don't know firebase but try this: .where("queueID", "==", 420).where("queueID", "==", 430).where("queueID", "==", 440)

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried this but it ended up only checking for things where the id was both 420 and 440 which is impossible since each thing only has 1 value for the id

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "in" operator if it's a fairly small number of items. Documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).